# How to read double summation where the outer summation begin where the inner summation ends

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, summation, notation

Hi I am not sure how to wrap my head around the summation at the end of equation $(3)$. Appreciate the help, thanks!

[image]

Comment: When $j=1$, there is one $k$ to add: $(j,k) = (1,1)$. When $j=2$: $(j,k)\in\{(2,1),(2,2)\}$. When $j=3$: $(j,k) \in\{(3,1), (3,2), (3,3)\}$. Up to $j=t$, where there are $t$ different $k$ values: $(j,k)\in\{(t,1), (t,2), \ldots, (t,t)\}$.

Comment: Suggest you write out the complete sum for a few small values of the upper index of the outer sum on the left side.

Comment: @peterwhy your logic seems to apply to the outer sum. I'm still confused about the k=1 to j part. I have to resolve that inner sum to work on the outer right?

Comment: @coffeemath I do that I get the sum of c1, c2, ... up to ct. And for the inner sum the end is just y^(j-1) * tau^(0)?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you meant by "resolve that inner sum". The number of terms in the inner sum depends on the outer index $j$. I expanded the double summation below, which is too long to be a comment.

Comment: You may be thinking about how to **simplify** the sum when you talk about having to resolve the inner sum first. But when it comes to the meaning of the sum itself (not a simplified formula), the outer summation is defined first; the inner summation is defined later and can depend on the outer summation.

Comment: @DavidK Yeah for this situation I need to use the outer variable j to begin the inner sum, was confused about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $j=1$, there is one $k$ to add: $(j,k) = (1,1)$. When $j=2$: $(j,k)\in\{(2,1),(2,2)\}$. When $j=3$: $(j,k) \in\{(3,1), (3,2), (3,3)\}$. Up to $j=t$, where there are $t$ different $k$ values: $(j,k)\in\{(t,1), (t,2), \ldots, (t,t)\}$.

To really expand and write that out:

$$\begin{align*}RHS
&= c_1\sum_{k=1}^1y^{k-1}\tau^{1-k}+c_2\sum_{k=1}^2y^{k-1}\tau^{2-k}+c_3\sum_{k=1}^3y^{k-1}\tau^{3-k}+\cdots +\rlap{c_t\sum_{k=1}^ty^{k-1}\tau^{t-k}}\\
&= c_1\left(y^{1-1}\tau^{1-1}\right)+c_2\left(y^{1-1}\tau^{2-1}+y^{2-1}\tau^{2-2}\right)&&(j=1,2)\\
&\quad+c_3\left(y^{1-1}\tau^{3-1}+y^{2-1}\tau^{3-2}+y^{3-1}\tau^{3-3}\right) &&(j=3)\\
&\quad+\cdots\\
&\quad+c_t\left(y^{1-1}\tau^{t-1}+y^{2-1}\tau^{t-2}+y^{3-1}\tau^{t-3} + \cdots + y^{t-1}\tau^{t-t}\right) &&(j=t)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks for the clear up! Seeing this expanded helps, I'm still staring at this to understand it more.